# How to request a exportable certificate using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, x509certificate

Refer to [Get-Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/get-certificate?view=win10-ps#syntax)
I tried to request a certificate using PowerShell, it worked but the certificate is not exportable, here is my command:

```
Get-Certificate -Template "MyComputer" -SubjectName "CN=corey.com" -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

When I try to export the certificate, it failed.

```
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert cert:\LocalMachine\My\$Thumbprint -FilePath C:\corey.com.pfx -Password $mypwd
```

The error message:

> Export-PfxCertificate: Cannot export non-exportable private key.

I can't find any parameter like `Exportable` or property for me to use with `Get-Certificate` command. Is there any way to request/make a certificate exportable by using PowerShell?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915305/export-pfxcertificate-cannot-export-non-exportable-private-key

Comment: @Scepticalist thanks for sharing but my critical problem is how can I make the certificate exportable while "requesting" by using PowerShell, any idea?

Comment: @Corey When you install the certificate it must be marked as exportable, if this isn't done its a one way process.

Comment: I think this will give you a child certificate from the Enrollment Server which basically means that you need to export the Pfx from the Enrollment Server itself. Another option is to create a self signed Certificate using New-SelfSignedCertificate then you will be able to export the pfx from the server you are at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause there is no parameter to make it exportable when using `Get-Certificate`, so I use `certreq` as a replacement to achieve my goal and post here hoping that could help someone else.

Firstly, prepare an information file, and set `Exportable` as `TRUE`.

```bsh
$file = @'
[NewRequest]
Subject = "CN=corey.com"
KeyLength = 2048
Exportable = TRUE
[RequestAttributes]
CertificateTemplate = "MyTemplate"
'@

Set-Content temp.inf $file
```

Secondly, type the following commands.

```bsh
# create a new request from an .inf file
certreq -new temp.inf temp.req

# submit a request to the certificate authority
certreq -submit -config CAHostName\CAName temp.req temp.cer

# accept and install a response to a certificate request
certreq -accept temp.cer
```

Finally, export the certificate and assign a password for it.

```bsh
$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert cert:\LocalMachine\My\$Thumbprint -FilePath C:\corey.com.pfx -Password $mypwd
```

For more details, please see [certreq - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certreq_1)